# ArcMap Caching Character Problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

i have a basemap which was created with arcmap and i want to use it for my application with cached. in my viewport in arcmap there is no any Turkish character problem on it but when i cache my work it makes character problem.

how can i accomplish this subject with settings ?

Comment: What do you mean by viewport? Are you saying that you've added the cached map service to ArcMap and not seeing any Turkish Characters in the cache. Is ArcMap and ArcGIS Server on the same machine. If different, I'd check if the language settings (and installed fonts) on both the machines are same.

Comment: i will check this thnk u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are caching with an optimized map service and see a difference between the cache and what you see in ArcMap, this could be because of differences between the way font fallback is handled.  Your font may not have Turkish characters, but Windows still draws something because it falls back to a font that does.  Optimized map services do not do this.  See [this article](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sq0000000w000000.htm) for more detail (text section at the bottom)